# OpenCV: Why *p_img1=*p_img2 is not correct

Tags: c++, opencv, iplimage

`p_img1` and `p_img2` being `IplImage*` previously cvLoad'ed, I would like `p_img1` to become a copy of `p_img2`.

Writing `*p_img1 = *p_img2;` seems to work fine (I can check it in debug mode, as well as by displaying images), except that after that line, using `cvReleaseImage` for one pointer will apparently also destroy the other one. I don't understand it as the two pointers (the two addresses) are different, only the fields of the structures are copied.

I noticed that using `p_img1 = cvCloneImage(p_img2);` fixes the problem.

Could somebody please explain why `*p_img1 = *p_img2` is wrong ? What `cvCloneImage()` does differently ?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using the deprecated C API anymore, especially when you've tagged your question as C++.

Comment: you copy the objects, but the objects might have member variables pointers to allocated memory which might be freed when you destroy/release the object. This is the case for image types like IplImage. cv::Mat has some reference counting for the same task, whuch is very nice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you to have some further reading on C++ pointer related references.

Your `p_img1` and `p_img2` are pointers to IplImage structure.

- `p_img1` pointing to imageheader1
- `p_img2` pointing to imageheader2

however, the `IplImage` structure does not contain the image data, instead it holds the pointer to memory location storing the pixel value.

- imageheader1 contains pointer to pixeldata1
- imageheader2 contains pointer to pixeldata2

Executing `*p_img1 = *p_img2`, will make the content of `p_img1` similar to `p_img2`, thus

- imageheader1 now contains pointer to pixeldata2
- imageheader2 still contains pointer to pixeldata2

pixeldata1 will be unreferenced and become potential memory leak if it is not released. When releasing, `cvReleaseImage` takes parameter of 'pointer of pointer', which actually releases the imageheader pointed, so both imageheader1 and imageheader2 will point to invalid memory.

`cvCloneImage` has built-in memory allocation, where it actually allocate new block of memory before copying the content into it. Executing `p_img1 = cvCloneImage(p_img2)` will cause OpenCV to allocate new memory block (pixeldata3), copying data from pixeldata2 (pointed by imageheader2 of `p_img2`) and then update the imageheader1 (pointed by `p_img1`).

- imageheader1 contains pointer to pixeldata3
- imageheader2 contains pointer to pixeldata2

=> pixeldata1 will be unreferenced and become potential memory leak if it is not released.